# What design pattern or caching strategy would suit this pattern?

Tags: java, caching, messaging, producer-consumer

I need to consume the services of a number of third party systems on my applications homepage. The data pertaining to these downstream systems are updated at different intervals and ideally my system will surface the latest data. It's not a scalable solution for my system to generate requests to each of these downstream systems each time a user hits my homepage. What strategy can i use to ensure the data i surface is current without effecting the reliability of these downstream systems?

Is a consumer/producer strategy most suitable for this requirement?

Comment: Can you alter / modify those third party systems?

Comment: I might use a caching HTTP proxy like squid; each downstream system must serve "cacheable" content for that to work effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other answers point out, caching sounds like a good strategy in your case.

An alternative, however, is using a *pubsub*-based design (not producer-consumer).  For example, you can have 3 threads sampling the serivces, each at its own rate, and *publishing* the new data. Your main system *subscribes* to those updates (can read them in another thread), and updates its internal state.

*Producer-consumer* is similar, but not suitable for your case, becuase there's no need for the client (your main system) to *consume* the data. Imagine you had several systems using the same data from the services -- each would need to *subscribe* to those updates, but not to *consume* them, as the update needs to reach all clients.  Producer-consumer is appropriate for things like task-pooling, where each worker needs to *consume* the message, because each task should be run by only one worker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need a strategy, you just need a cache.

Pick what your maximum time interval for polls is. The code that fetches the data just remembers the result and the time it fetched it. Until the time interval expires it returns the cached data instead of querying again. Once the time is reached next request fetches the new data...

The cache time is a judgement call based on how fast the data might go out of date as opposed to how nice you want to be to the downstream systems. (And be aware that in many systems if you flood them with requests they will shut you out anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check **memcache**, we used it in a project involving ton of web service invocations and it worked like charm.